# How to get 0 from max function incase there are no records

Tags: mysql

I have a table , from which i am getting max value , but incase of no records how to get value as 0 instead of null

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_details` (
  `video_id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Auto Generated key',
  `video_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=382 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my query

```
select max(vd.video_id) as count from video_details vd;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ifnull`

```
select ifnull(max(vd.video_id),0) as count from video_details vd;
```

Answer (score 2):

use [COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

```
 select COALESCE (max(vd.video_id),0) as count 
 from video_details vd;
```

Comment: i am getting function COALESCE  does not exist.

Comment: You are free to choose the answer better help you with your issue. But why I lose the accepted answer? both answer are equal correct. But `ifnull` is specific for mysql, `coalesce` is ANSI standard so work in all db.  I even give you a working demo, and finally my answer was publish first.